# PopupWindow not shown as expected (preview is ok)

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow, android-popupwindow

I'm trying to show a full screen popup window from a fragment. I was starting the layout for the screen and it looked as expected in the AS screen preview, but it doesn't when it is executed in a device. Basically, it seems that the paddings are omitted. All of them, the paddings in the root of the layout, in the image view which I put to increase the clickable area, in the text input layout (added by theme).
On the other hand, the animation is not shown in some devices but in emulator is.
Here is the layout file ``:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_start"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_end"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bt_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_size_x2_5"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Touche.H3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Product"
        android:text="Product"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bt_close"
        tools:textColorHint="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_add_item"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Touche.Button.Primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:text="@string/add_order_add__to_order"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/ti_quantity"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_size_x10"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_size_x6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bt_close">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_quantity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="50"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_start"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_end"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom"
            android:text="0" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_less"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_start"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_end"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_less_selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ti_quantity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ti_quantity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ti_quantity" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_start"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_end"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ti_quantity"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ti_quantity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ti_quantity" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here you have the kotlin code inside a fragment:

```kotlin
context?.let {
    val customView: View = (it.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater).inflate(R.layout.popup_add_item, null)
    val popupWindow = PopupWindow(it)
    popupWindow.contentView = customView
    popupWindow.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    popupWindow.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    popupWindow.animationStyle = R.style.popup_window_animation // TODO Not working in some devices
    popupWindow.elevation = 5f
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(getBinding().rvDiscounts, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
    val btClose = customView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.bt_close)
    val btAddToCart = customView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.bt_add_item)
    val btAdd = customView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.bt_add)
    val btLess = customView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.bt_less)
    val etQuantity = customView.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.et_quantity)
    btClose.setOnClickListener {
        popupWindow.dismiss()
    }
    btAddToCart.setOnClickListener {
        // TODO add to cart
        popupWindow.dismiss()
    }
    btAdd.setOnClickListener {
        val currentQuantity = etQuantity.text.toString().toInt()
        etQuantity.setText(currentQuantity.inc().toString())
    }
    btLess.setOnClickListener {
        val currentQuantity = etQuantity.text.toString().toInt()
        if (currentQuantity > 0) etQuantity.setText(currentQuantity.dec().toString())
    }
}
```

And finally the screenshots, the preview and expected first, the shown on the device second:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. To the plus and minus button use a `android:margin_start="8dp"` and `android:margin_end="8dp"` respectively, to get some space between the `button` and the `TextInputEditText` box.
2. If you wish to center the zero within TextInputEditText then use `android:gravity="center"`
3. The `@dimen/padding_start` values in these might not be acceptable, so just hardcode the values using `android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"` and `android:paddingVertical="8dp"`.

Comment: Same result with hard coded values. In any case, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme.FullScreenDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

> Use this style while creating your Dialog in the fragment like this :

```
 var fullScreenCameraDialog = Dialog(context, R.style.AppTheme_FullScreenDialog)
```